# How does FormsAuthentication persist sessions across request contexts and what information is persisted?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So, I call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true)` and redirect to an `[Authorize]` branded action. Now `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` is a `FormsIdentity` whose properties advise me that I am indeed logged in. Great.

Now I remodel my database, deleting the tables and regenerating them. The name being persisted by FormsAuthentication doesn't even exist any more. But when I refresh the secure web site, the stupid logic still greets me: Hello *UserName*.  Okay... that's cool.

FormsAuthentication is obviously not tied to my data store. Is it storing session information in-process? Or is it encoding all relevant data in to the authentication ticket and letting the client persist it in cookies?

Lastly, is the ticket tied to my membership platform at all? Or is `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` just an arbitrary value?

Comment: Is the session provider specified in the web.config?

Comment: No, sir. Just the membership provider.

Comment: Have you tried to authorize against a role after deleting the membership tables?

Comment: @dtryon: Actually, I haven't implemented any roles yet. A role provider isn't defined in web.config and I'm not authorizing against them.

Comment: "But when I refresh the secure web site..." A lot of things are in play here... by default session is 'inproc' and therefore if you don't restart the web server (recycle app pools, whatever is appropriate for whatever server you are testing against) the sessionid for the previously issued cookie is still valid until the timeout. I suspect that if you *also* restart your server, you'll see that it is working as expected.

Comment: @ChrisKeller: I haven't got a straight answer if the session store is actually used to persist forms authentication data. I have an answer which implicitly says it does not.

Comment: Default, no. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx My point about the session was that by default the machinekey is set to 'auto' which means asp.net will generate a new one every time it starts up. Because of this, any persisted cookies that had the previous machinekey (decryptionKey attribute) can no longer be decrypted and therefore the client will be forced to authenticate again. That was my thought process when I wrote the above. A more careful reading of your question prompted my answer below that specifically addresses your questions.

Comment: @ChrisKeller: The machine key is a fair point. Though I didn't stipulate it in the question, I wrote a fixed machine key in my web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default forms authentication configuration a cookie is sent to the client upon successful login. (there are cookieless options)

"Each time a subsequent request is received after authentication, the FormsAuthenticationModule class retrieves the authentication ticket from the authentication cookie, decrypts it, computes the hash value, and compares the MAC value to help ensure that the cookie has not been tampered with."

What you are seeing is the FormsAuthenticationModule finding that the request has a cookie.

The following link is a very detailed overview of the process that I just described. The activity diagram is particularly important to understanding what happens with each request.

I hope that helps.

[Explained: Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)

Chris

Answer (score 2):

All relevant data is stored in the authentication ticket and persisted in a cookie on the client side. And HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is stored in another cookie as well. You can see the cookies with firefox by clicking View page info and then security. You will see 2 cookies. One of them is .ASPXAUTH (takes care of authentication), and the other one .ASPXROLES(takes care of membership).

Comment: How is anti-spoofing handled? Doesn't there need to be some server-side backing?

Comment: i don't know the exact algorithms they use but the data in the cookies is encoded somehow or at least scrambled.

Comment: Yes, it is encrypted (configurable). Please see my answer for the details, but here is the important part:

"Encrypt forms authentication ticket. The second byte array that has been created is encrypted by using the Encrypt method of the FormsAuthentication class. The Encrypt method internally uses the algorithm and key specified by the decryption and decryptionKey attributes on the machineKey element. ASP.NET version 1.1 uses the 3DES algorithm by default. ASP.NET version 2.0 uses the Rinjdael (AES) algorithm by default."